# WooCommerce 502 Bad gateway when using add_to_cart function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

As the title says, I'm getting Error 502 Bad Gateway when I try to use the standard function add_to_cart() from WooCommerce

```
WC()->cart->add_to_cart( 8622 );
```

Any ideas what's going on? I also tried adding more arguments to the function such as the quantity and etc but doesn't seems to change anything...

WooCommerce documentation: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html

Comment: Step 1) Check your PHP and web server logs.

Comment: @AlexHowansky error.log:
`2017/11/01 18:11:35 [error] 46200#46200: *2480780 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 92.53.xx.xxx, server: www.xxx.com.au, request: "GET /cart/ HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php7-fpm-xxx.sock:", host: "xxx.com"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have managed to fix this by making another function to be called in the function.php file. I am not sure why this works now since it's the same concept, except that the function is now called from the functions.php file from the theme.

Here's the code for anyone that needs this:

```
// Add item to cart
function add_id_to_cart( $product_id ) {
    $flag = true;
    //check if product already in cart
    foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $key => $val ) {
        $_product = $val['data'];

        if($product_id == $_product->id ) {
            $flag = false;
        }
    }
    // if product not in cart, add it
    if ( $flag ) {
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
    }
}
```